# Radiobutton style as toggle button in xaml

Tags: xaml, radio-button, togglebutton

I have 2 button which should act as switch, so i use radio button. But the styling of the radio button should look like toggle button, which means, it should not be having a circle to check.

I searched for long time with no helpful resources.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style> 


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BgColor}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource FgColor}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HoverColor}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBlack}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBlack}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HoverColor}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

But it is leaving a space black for circle (radio property) and on mouse Hover, it is showing up the circle to check..

Can anyone know the easiest way to achieve it ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you really need to do is define styling for your RadioButtons to look like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Path=(Content), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}"
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=(IsChecked), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

That's your core. You can add whatever you need to add as another Setters, or style ToggleButton in the ControlTemplate to look like you want it to.

Comment: The same is present in App.Xaml which i mentioned .. But the issue i am facing is: 1) Default mode: it does not show any circle as expected but leaves the space for that 2) On mouse hover: circle does apper back again

Comment: Ok, my solution for some reason works only if there are no explicit styling applied to this controls... Let me edit it to solve your problem.